# Finding patterns in Puzzle games

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, puzzle

I was wondering, which are the most commonly used algorithms applied to finding patterns in puzzle games conformed by grids of cells.

I know that depends of many factors, like the kind of patterns You want to detect, or the rules of the game...but I wanted to know which are the most commonly used algorithms in that kind of problems...

For example, games like columns, bejeweled, even tetris.

I also want to know if detecting patterns by "brute force" ( like , scanning all the grid trying to find three adyacent cells of the same color ) is significantly worst that using particular algorithms in very small grids, like 4 X 4 for example ( and again, I know that depends of the kind of game and rules ...)

Which structures are commonly used in this kind of games ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always domain-dependent. But there's also two situations where you'd do these kinds of searches. Ones situation is after a move (a change to the game field made by the player), and the other would be if/when the whole board has changed.

In Tetris, you wouldn't need to scan the whole board after a piece is dropped. You'd just have to search the rows the piece is touching.

In a match-3 games like Bejeweled, where you're swapping two adjacent pieces at a time, you'd first run a localized search in each direction around each square that changed, to see if any pieces have triggered. Then, if they have, the game will dump some new, random pieces onto the board. Now, you could run the same localized search around each square that's changed, but that might involve a lot of `if` statements and might actually be slower to just scanning the whole board from top left to bottom right. It depends on your implementation and would require profiling.

As Adrian says, a simple 2D array suffices. Often, though, you may add a "border" of pixels around this array, to simplify the searching-for-patterns aspect. Without a border, you'd have to have `if` statements along the edge squares that says "well, if you're in the top row, don't search up (and walk off the array)". With a border around it, you can safely just search through everything: saving yourself `if` statements, saving yourself branching, saving yourself pipeline issues, searching faster.

To Jon: these kinds of things really do matter in high-performance settings, even on modern machines, if you're making a search algorithm to play/solve the game. If you are, you want your underlying simulation to run as quickly as possible in order to search as deep as possible in the fewest cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding algorithms: It certainly depends on the game. For example for tetris, you'd only have to scan each row if it has the same color. I can't even think of something that would not equal the brute force approach in this case. But for most casual games brute force should be perfectly fine. Pattern recognition should be negligible in comparison to graphics and sound processing.

Regarding structures: A simple 2D-Array should suffice for representing the board.

Answer (score 0):

Given the average computer speed these days, if it's real-time as the user is playing the game, it probably won't matter (EDIT: for very small game boards only). Certainly, it would depend on the complexity of the game logic, but also how fast the code is going to run on the target machine (i.e., is this a JavaScript web page game, or a Windows app written in C++).

If this is for something like simulating gameplay strategies, then use an algorithm that's more efficient.

A more efficient strategy could involve keeping track of incremental changes to the game board, instead of re-scanning the whole board every time.